# Cannot borrow `*x` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Tags: rust, immutability, mutable, borrowing

I'm making a Combinatory Optimization project to learn Rust and I've got a problem I cannot resolve myself...

I've got 2 functions :

```
pub fn get_pareto_front_offline<'a>(scheduling_jobs: &'a Vec<Vec<u32>>, costs_vector: &'a Vec<(u32, u32)>) -> Vec<(&'a Vec<u32>, &'a (u32, u32))> {
    // ...
}
```

and

```
pub fn pareto_approach_offline<'a>(list_of_jobs: &'a mut Vec<Vec<u32>>, neighborhood: &'a mut Vec<Vec<u32>>, costs: &'a Vec<(u32, u32)>) -> Vec<(&'a Vec<u32>, &'a (u32, u32))> {
    let pareto_front = get_pareto_front_offline(neighborhood, costs);

    loop {
        if pareto_front == vec![] {
            break;
        }

        neighborhood.clear();

        for front in pareto_front.iter() {
            neighborhood.push((front.0).clone());
        }
    }

    pareto_front
}
```

I've got a problem because the compiler tells me:

```
cannot borrow '*neighborhood' as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutableat line 15 col 9
cannot borrow '*neighborhood' as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutableat line 19 col 13
```

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to do something fundamentally impossible.

When you call `get_pareto_front_offline`, you pass a re-borrowing of `neighborhood` into that function.  This re-borrow *must* be maintained in order for `pareto_front` to remain valid.  In other words, as long as `pareto_front` exists, the compiler will *not* allow you to access `neighborhood` in any fashion whatsoever.

This is a good thing, because you then proceed to try and clear our `neighborhood`, which would almost *certainly* invalidate `pareto_front`, likely leading to use-after-free and corrupting your program's state.

It's not clear what it is you're attempting to do; but you *cannot* do it this way.

As an aside, even if it compiled, that loop would probably never finish running: your termination condition (`pareto_front == vec![]`) will never be satisfied because you never modify `pareto_front`; it'll either stop immediately, or run forever.

The simplest way to get out from under borrowing problems is to make copies of things, so that you don't *need* a long-lived borrow; if `get_pareto_front_offline` returned a `Vec<(Vec<u32>, (u32, u32))>` instead, you wouldn't have this issue.  That, or modify to code to not touch `neighborhood` once you call `get_pareto_front_offline`.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is exactly what I'm thinking... I'm trying to make an optimized solution to this problem, but with my "level" in Rust, it's really hard :-/

Comment: In situations like this you often need a specialized collection. I believe that `VecDeque` can solve the problem, (but I may be wrong)

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html

Alternatively you can use channels 

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/

Answer (score 6):

In this case the compiler helped you avoid a use-after-free error by not accepting the code. The problem can be reduced to this piece of code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![0,1,2,3];
    let r = &v[2];
    v.push(5);
    println!("{}", *r); // oops
}
```

A Vec has a length and a capacity. If length equals capacity it means that there is no space left in the buffer for a new element. In such a case `push` involves moving all the elements to a new buffer that is big enough to store new data. But this action would invalidate the reference `r` because `r` still stores the old and now invalid address of the 3rd vector element. This is exactly the kind of error Rust is trying to prevent with the borrowing rules and the borrow checker.

But if you just add new stuff to the vector, it won't change the order of the elements that were already in there. Maybe you could just replace some references to Vec elements with indices which stay the same regardless of where the Vec elements are stored.

Some aside suggestions: Prefer `&[T]` over `&Vec<T>` for function arguments. It's more flexible. Also, `pareto_front == vec![]` can be replaced with `pareto_front.is_empty()`.